# Sublime Text custom highlighting $

Tags: sublime-text

How can I customize the syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3? In particular, I'd like to ignore text delimeted by `$` (as well as suppressing the 'closing' `$` whenever I type `$`).

I am using `LaTeXTools`.

I have tried to use `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`, and viewing the `LaTeX.sublime-syntax` YAML resource, but the only line relating to `$` that I could see is:

```
 - match: '(?:<|>)(\{)\$(\})'
      scope: meta.column-specials.latex
      captures:
        1: punctuation.definition.column-specials.begin.latex
        2: punctuation.definition.column-specials.end.latex
    - include: scope:text.tex
```

I don't understand this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't find the rule is because, in the current version of the syntax, it's not in `LaTeX.sublime-syntax`, but in `TeX.sublime-syntax`, where you'll find:

```
- match: \$\$
  captures:
    0: punctuation.definition.string.begin.tex
  push:
    - meta_scope: string.other.math.block.tex
    - match: \$\$
      captures:
        0: punctuation.definition.string.end.tex
      pop: true
    - include: scope:text.tex.math
    - include: main
```

and

```
- match: \$
  captures:
    0: punctuation.definition.string.begin.tex
  push:
    - meta_scope: string.other.math.tex
    - match: \$
      captures:
        0: punctuation.definition.string.end.tex
      pop: true
    - match: \\\$
      scope: constant.character.escape.tex
    - include: scope:text.tex.math
    - include: main
```

You can change the `meta_scope` property. I'd recommend changing the first to `meta.environment.math.block.dollar.latex` and the second to `meta.environment.math.inline.dollar.latex`, as these are the scopes used in the revision of the LaTeX syntax that will be in the next beta, and they will ensure that math mode completions will continue to work. If you don't care about math mode completions, you can change them to whatever you want.

Overriding the `$` keybindings is quite a bit different. Select **Preferences | Key Bindings – User** and add the following key binding:

```
{"keys": ["$"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\\$"}, 
    "context": [
        {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"}
    ] 
}
```

Bear in mind that this is one entry in a JSON list so the file should start with `[` end with `]` and you need a comma before it if there are preceding entries, etc. (See [the docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) on this). This simply tells ST to insert a `$` when you type `$` in a LaTeX document.